# Another diffusion partial differential equation, or Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

What is the solution for the following diffusion partial differential equation (initial value problem)?
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \pm\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+(ax+b)^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2},$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real number constants.

We can separate the variables or take the Fourier transform $\tilde f(x)$ of $f$ in the time domain $t$, and turn the above into an ordinary differential equation eigenvalue problem in $x$:
$$k\tilde f= \pm\frac{d\tilde f}{d x}+(ax+b)^2\frac{d^2 \tilde f}{d x^2}.$$
where $k$ can be views as an eigenvalue for the differential operator on the left hand side. Now we can further transform this into the [Sturm-Liouville form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-liouville).

However, I can not immediate recognize a transformation that can turn the above into a known form that admits an analytic solution. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple finds solutions of the ODE (with +) in terms of Kummer U and M functions:
$$f \left( x \right) = \left( ax+b \right) ^{-{\frac {\sqrt {{a}^{2
}+4\,k}-a}{2a}}} \left( C_{{1}}\;{\text{KummerU}\left({\frac {\sqrt {{a}^{2
}+4\,k}-a}{2a}},\,{\frac {a+\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4\,k}}{a}},\,{\frac {1}{
 \left( ax+b \right) a}}\right)}+C_{{2}}\;{\text{KummerM}\left({\frac {
\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4\,k}-a}{2a}},\,{\frac {a+\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4\,k}}{a}},\,{
\frac {1}{ \left( ax+b \right) a}}\right)} \right) 
$$

EDIT:

If you take your ODE $(ax+b)^2 f''(x) + f'(x) - k f(x) = 0$ 
and do the change of dependent and independent variables $f(x) = z^c u(z)$, $x = \dfrac{1}{a^2 z} - \dfrac{b}{a}$ with constant $c$ to be determined, you get

$$ z\; u''(z) + (2c+2 - z) \; u'(z) + \left(\dfrac{a^2 c^2 + a^2 c - k}{a^2 z} - c \right) u = 0$$

Set $c$ such that $a^2 c^2 + a^2 c - k = 0$, the above equation turns into the Kummer equation

$$ z \; u'' + (\nu - z) u' - \mu u = 0$$
with $\nu = 2c+2$ and $\mu = c$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to give further the transformation which turns the original ODE into a Kummer equation?

Comment: Excellent! What happens when $a^2c^2+a^2c−k \ne 0$? What motivates you to search for the transformation of this form? Is there a general theory behind it? Is it the theory of hypergeometry differential equations?

Comment: When $a^2 c^2 + a^2 c - k \ne 0$, the coefficient of $u$ has a term in $1/z$, so it's not the Kummer equation.  What motivates me?  As I said, Maple returned the solution in terms of the Kummer functions, and I took a change of variable that made that solution a linear combination of KummerU(..., z) and KummerM(..., z).  There is a general theory of symmetry for differential equations, which Maple makes extensive use.  See e.g. http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve/references

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and reference. So when the solution is not the Kummer equation, is there no special function expression for the solution?

Comment: The solutions are **always** the expression I gave.  When $a^2 c^2 + a^2 c - k \ne 0$, the transformation does not give a Kummer equation, but a different choice of $c$ does.

Comment: Right, I forgot $c$ was to be chosen so that the equation $a^2c^2+a^2c-k=0$ hold. I took the liberty to change the wording regarding that equation of $c$ in your answer so as to make this even clearer. Please let me know if you agree with the modification.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Oh, but what if the discriminant of the quadratic equation is negative, or $k< -\frac{a^2}{4}$? The square roots in the answer are going to be pure imaginary. Do we take the real and imaginary parts or perhaps Kummer function turns into some other form?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of a complex solution will be solutions.  I don't know of a special form for the Kummer functions with complex parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to find any nontrivial solution of the ODE.

Note first that if $\alpha = 0$, then the answer is trivial. Because it will be simple linear homogeneous equation with constant coefficients.

Assume that $\alpha \neq 0$.
As far as I understand, you can take almost any $k$ (with except $k =0$), since it doesn't depend on initial conditions. Let us try to find a solution in the form
$$
\tilde{f} = x^2 + \beta  x + \gamma.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\frac{d \tilde{f}}{dx} = 2 x + \beta, \quad \frac{d^2 \tilde{f}}{dx^2} = 2.
$$
Substituting these equalities into your expression, we get
$$
k x^2 + \beta k x + \gamma k = \pm (2 x + \beta) + 2 (a^2 x^2 + 2 a b x + b^2).
$$
Therefore,
$$
(2a^2 -k) x^2 + (4 a b \pm 2 - \beta k)x + (2 b^2 \pm \beta - \gamma k) = 0.
$$
Now we want expression in every bracket to be zero. 
For the first bracket we take $k = 2 a^2$. After that we can find $\beta$ from the second bracket, and finally $\gamma$ from the third.
Hence, function $\tilde{f} = x^2 + \beta  x + \gamma$ satisfies your ODE, that is, $\tilde{f}$ is a solution.

Comment: Good try, Voliar. There should be countably infinitely many eigenfunctions and (real) eigenvalues. I thought of power series solution, but did not actually try... I will later. In the mean time, is that a special function solution for this eigenvalue problem?

Comment: $\tilde{f}$ becomes an eigenfunction of this ODE with corresponding eigenvalue $k = 2 a^2$. In this sense, it is a solution of eigenvalue problem. Surely, if the question was to find all possible solutions, then my answer is not correct. In that case my misunderstanding was in the phrase "analytical solution".

Comment: I agree that what you have found is one of the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. I would like to find all possible solutions. Power series solutions are analytical. Actually it is the definition of analyticity. In fact all solution should be meromorphic, because the coefficients are analytical functions. But maybe I should take this adjective out, as it is redundant. I am going to do that.